# How to integrate tesseract-ocr with tika?

Tags: tesseract, apache-tika

I need to integrate the tesseract-ocr which converts scanned image as pdf to text.

There is tesseractOCRParser already available.

But there is no invoke method given.

When I am trying to build tika with tesseract-ocr referral path I am getting the following  error

Results:

```
Failed tests:   
testNoConfig(org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRConfigTest): 
Invalid default tesseractPath value expected:<[]> but was: 
<[/home/serendio/tesseract-ocr/]>

Tests run: 569, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 7
```

Can anyone help me out ???

Or any other-way to resolve this problem??

Comment: Do you have Tesseract installed? And how are you trying to call / use Tika?

Comment: Yea . i have tesseract in my machine . by referring tesseract path from my machine  am trying to build the tika   .jar  for my system.

The problem is tika source not builds with tesseract source.

Comment: Why are you trying to build Tika from source? To get started, you're much better off just downloading pre-build binaries, at least until you're used to it all

Answer (score 2):

I think this can help :
https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaOCR
I followed this guide and I was able to easily extract the content!
I simply installed Tesseract and then Tika.

Using Tika 1.9 I was easily able to :
 - extract the content directly calling a local Tika server
 - extract the content in a custom application ( you can use the tika-example project) with no effort .

No modification was needed. Everything working out of the box.